The puzzling interaction between an anapole moment and external fields
Consider an electrical current distribution with only an [anapole, or toroidal moment] but no electrical or magnetic multipole moments, like this current on a torus:

Its magnetic field is completely contained within the torus and on the outside there is no $E$-field, no $B$-field, but only a vector potential $A$ (in the Lorenz gauge). So the question arises, does this interact with an external field? To be precise:

Would this object emit radiation if rotated around an horizontal axis?

Would there be a torque on the object if placed in a time-varying field? (For instance a plane wave going from left to right and horizontally polarized, so with vertical $B$, would seem to give out-of-phase, non-canceling torques on the current loops left and right!)


I'm asking because the expansion of radiation in multipole fields, as for instance here in  [Jackson], suggests that without multipole moments there is no radiation. Of course for question 1) we can argue that a rotating anapole obtains non-vanishing multipole moments. But in 2) there is only the anapole, so we should then (perhaps) conclude that to find the force and torque on an object in fluctuating EM fields it is not sufficient to know all its electric and magnetic multipole moments?

Mathematically, a dipole can be seen as a small current loop. Given the dipole moment $m$ this gives the magnetisation and current density:
$$
M = m\delta \quad j = \nabla\times M = \nabla\times (m\delta)
$$
Similarly, a toroidal moment can be seen as a small dipole loop. Given the toroidal moment $\tau$, this gives the toroidal density, magnetisation and current density:
$$
T = \tau\delta \quad M =\nabla\times T= \nabla \times (\tau\delta) \quad j = \nabla\times(\nabla\times(\tau\delta))
$$
Since:
$$
\nabla\cdot M = 0
$$
You do have in magnetostatics:
$$
B = \mu_0M
$$
i.e. it is supported inside the torus.
For your first question, you do not need to rotate the toroidal moment to make it radiate. Simply varying the toroidal moment suffices. A rotating toroidal (resp. dipole) moment can be viewed as a superposition of orthogonal toroidal (resp. dipole) moment in phase quadrature. Equivalently, it just means that one of the components of $\tau$ are real and imaginary:
$$
\tau = (1,i,0)
$$
You cannot view this current distribution as a multipole, in the sense that the currents and charges cannot be obtained by a superposition of electric and magnetic charges. However, the field is part of the systematic vector spherical harmonic expansion. While the toroidal moment does not generate new multipole moments, it does generate the same field as the one generated by a multipole.
To see this you can look at the vector spherical harmonic expansion. I will stay in frequency space, with the convention:
$$
f(t) = \int \hat f(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\quad
\hat f(\omega) = \int f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt
$$
Let the Green's function and $x = \omega r$:
$$
G \propto \omega(h_0Y_{1m}+h_0\Psi_{1m})
$$
For the spherical Hankel function, add $(1)$ for causal solutions and $(2)$ for anti causal solutions. There is a numerical prefactor due to the normalisation of the harmonics which will always be the same. If the dipoles/anapoles point in the $z$ direction, $m=0$, if they rotate in the $xy$ plane $m=\pm1$ (clockwise/counterclowckwise).

For an electric dipole:
$$
\begin{align}
E &\propto (\nabla\otimes\nabla+\omega^2)pG & B &\propto -i\omega \nabla\times pG \\
&\propto \omega^3p\left((h_0''+h_0)Y_{1m}+\left(h_0+\frac{h_0'}x\right)\Psi_{1m}\right) & B &\propto -i\omega^3ph_0'\Phi_{1m}
\end{align}
$$
For an a magnetic dipole:
$$
\begin{align}
E &= i\omega \nabla\times mG & B &= \nabla\times(\nabla\times mG) \\
E &\propto -i\omega^3mh_0'\Phi_{1m} & B &\propto -\omega^3m\left(\frac{2h_0'}xY_{1m}+\left(h_0''+\frac1xh_0'\right)\Psi_{1m}\right)
\end{align}
$$
For the magnetic toroidal dipole:
$$
\begin{align}
E &= i\omega \nabla\times(\nabla\times \tau G) & B &= \nabla\times(\nabla\times(\nabla\times \tau G)) \\
E &\propto -i\omega^4\tau\left(\frac{2h_0'}xY_{1m}+\left(h_0''+\frac{h_0'}x\right)\Psi_{1m}\right) & B &\propto \omega^4\tau h_0'\Phi_{1m}
\end{align}
$$

Thus, the radiating field of the magnetic toroidal dipole is the same as the electric dipole field using the correspondence:
$$
p = i\omega \tau \quad p = -\dot \tau
$$
You can see this in Fourier space as well. I will use the convention:
$$
f(t,x) = \int \hat f(\omega,x)e^{-i\omega t+ik\cdot x}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \quad \hat f(\omega,x) = \int f(t,x)e^{i\omega t-ik\cdot x}dtd^3x
$$

For an electric dipole:
$$
\begin{align}
E &= -(k\otimes k-\omega^2)\frac p{k^2-\omega^2} & B &= -i\omega ik\times \frac p{k^2-\omega^2}
\end{align}
$$
For a magnetic toroidal dipole:
$$
\begin{align}
E &=i\omega ik\times\left(ik\times\frac \tau{k^2-\omega^2}\right) & B &= ik\times\left(ik\times\left(ik\times\frac \tau{k^2-\omega^2}\right)\right) \\
&=-i\omega(k\otimes k-\omega^2)\frac\tau{k^2-\omega^2}+i\omega\tau & &= \omega^2ik\times\frac{\tau}{k^2-\omega^2}+ik\times\tau
\end{align}
$$

So both agree up to local terms at the origin:
$$
E_\tau = E_p-\dot\tau\delta \quad B_\tau = B_p+\nabla\delta\times\tau
$$
using the same substitution:
$$
p = i\omega\tau \quad p = -\dot\tau
$$
For your second question, as you have pointed out by a reaction argument, remote currents cannot apply a magnetostatic force or torque on the magnetic toroidal dipoles. Given an external magnetic field $B_e$ generated by currents $j_e$:
$$
F = \mu_0\nabla(\tau\cdot j_e) \\
\Gamma = \mu_0\tau\times j_e
$$
i.e. you get the same formulas as for the dipole, replacing the magnetic field by its curl (the source current).
With an external dynamic EM field, you just need to replace the previous curl of the magnetic field by its corrected form:
$$
F = \mu_0\nabla[\tau\cdot (j_e+\epsilon_0 \partial_tE_e)] \\
\Gamma = \mu_0\tau\times (j_e+\epsilon_0\partial_tE_e)
$$
For a remote current distribution, the first terms are zero. Therefore, all you need is a time varying electric field at the magnetic toroidal dipole to get a torque (whose time derivative is not parallel to the toroidal moment).
Comment about knzhou's answer
The reason why knzhou's results are opposite of mine is that we are not describing the same things. knzhou considers the coupling with the EM field via anapole terms:
$$
\mathcal L_I = \mathcal A^\mu\partial^\nu F_{\mu\nu}
$$
and takes an ideal anapole to be:
$$
\mathcal A^0 = 0\quad \vec{\mathcal A} = \vec a\delta
$$
This does not correspond to a magnetic toroidal dipole (at least the one I was considering). In Fourier space, my ideal magnetic toroidal dipole has the anapole field (in Fourier space):
$$
\mathcal A^0 = \omega \vec k\cdot\frac{\vec \tau}{\vec k{}^2-\omega^2} \quad \vec{\mathcal A} = \vec k{}^2\frac{\vec \tau}{\vec k{}^2-\omega^2}
$$
This is why my localised toroidal dipole can interact with remote charges and currents despite the contact interaction: it has a delocalised anapole distribution supported on the entirety of spacetime. The definition of magnetic toroidal dipole and anapole match in the static case, which is consistent with the fact that there is no remote interactions for either of them.

Thanks, @LPZ, but could you please elaborate:

What multipole radiation do we get? (I never wrote it would be a dipole, but is it a magnetic quadrupole? Any of the usual electric/magnetic multipoles? Or something more complicated?)
Your claim about the torque in a static external field looks puzzling! The anapole would then have to exert an opposite torque on the field sources but the (stationary) anapole has only a pure gauge field around it (a rotation-free $A$), so it can't produce any forces, nor torque, on any arrangement of source magnets you would choose!



Sorry, didn't read your question attentively, modified accordingly and added some details.  2) Yes, you are absolutely correct. I forgot a second term in the expression of the torque which is why my original answer was incorrect.


On 2) we then seem to agree (so we could still both be wrong...) But for 1) I would expect that there has to be one of the ordinary multipole radiation patterns, simply because in that expansion (vector spherical harmonics with outgoing spherical Hankel functions) we use a complete basis, so there is no room for anything new! And since in the near field zone we just get the induction field of a ring core transformer, which is an electric dipole pattern, I think an oscillating anapole must be an electric dipole radiator. (Rotating will then give us two of those in quadrature phase).

Yes, you have a basis, but not using only physical multipoles. You need to include toroidal moments and its generalisation which are independent functions and thus complete the basis. For completeness, I've added the resulting fields that you can compare to the dipolar ones.

That seems incorrect, you cannot "unprove" the fact that outside the source region the free fields are completely described by only the coefficients $a_E$ and $a_M$ of the electric and magnetic multipole radiation, as in Eq. 16.46 of Jackson: https://archive.org/details/ClassicalElectrodynamics2nd/page/n773/mode/2up?view=theater
In addition, Jackson's Eq. 16.19 correctly derives the electric dipole coefficient for a time-varying toroidal current $J$ in the anapole drawing above (which has no $\mathcal M$ or $\rho$). So there's nothing new required...

Of course if you want to describe the non-free fields inside the source region, the basis  for free fields would not suffice. Also the current distributions of the sources themselves need the larger basis where you add toroidal patterns. But that is irrelevant for the radiation that leaves the source region. That radiation has to obey the free-field equations and therefore consists only of the well-known, old-fashioned electric and magnetic multipole fields. (By working in momentum space we just don't see these things clearly because all regions are mixed up...)

My answer does not contradict Jackson, but is rather supported by it. This is what I mention in the paragraph after the field expressions. The anapole term is not a new term in the general vector multipole expansion. Only, the terms electric/magnetic dipole refer to the scalar multipole expansion, which is not as general. This is why the anapole is a vector multipole moment but does not correspond to an electric/magnetic dipole.

Some things in that paragraph are wrong if we look outside the source region, i.e. at the radiation (that's what the question was about). The fields of the anapole and the electric dipole are not different there, there's no ambiguity in the term multipole there. Furthermore, the terms electric/magnetic dipole are not restricted to scalar multipole expansions, we describe dipole radiation by vector spherical harmonics! And we do recover the radiation field of an oscillating anapole by replacing it by an oscillating dipole of two electric charges. So we have $4$ disagreements, correct?!

My third equation displays the static case for simplicity, but the first equation is fully dynamical and shows that the interaction vanishes in the presence of any source-free field, including radiation. I'm not sure what you mean by "radiative corrections". If you mean loop corrections, that certainly can't be relevant to a question about classical electromagnetism. If you mean radiation, that's already accounted for in my first equation.

There's a chance that we're actually agreeing on everything but using different words to describe the same result. Would you agree that if there's a point-like anapole at the origin, and there are other charges and currents which do not overlap the origin, then those other charges feel no effect from the anapole? That's what I mean by it being a contact interaction.

Just realised that we are not describing the same things. Putting everything in a common ground, our answers are consistent with each other

Thanks, your newest edit is very illuminating! It's interesting that these two definitions sound conceptually similar, both emerge naturally, and match at $\omega = 0$, yet differ at $\omega \neq 0$.

A pure anapole produces no radiation, no matter how it is varied or rotated, and has no interaction with free external fields. Sources online seem to disagree on this point, but it might be because of the varying ways people define "anapole moment". (In particular, there was a robust literature on them and other moments in the former Soviet Union, which I never understood.) I'm going to use the definition that follows naturally from field theory.
The simplest thing that can have an anapole moment is a spin $1/2$ particle. The interaction term is
$$L_{\mathrm{ana}} \propto \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \, \bar{\Psi} \gamma^\mu \gamma^5 \Psi \, \partial^\nu F_{\mu\nu}.$$
On the other hand, we know that
$$\partial^\nu F_{\mu\nu} = J^\mu$$
where $J^\mu$ is the external four-current. So away from other sources, the anapole interaction vanishes. We can see this more concretely by taking the single particle limit: when the particle is at rest, the interaction above yields the Hamiltonian
$$H_{\mathrm{ana}} \propto \mathbf{S} \cdot \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x})$$
where $\mathbf{S}$ is the particle's spin, parallel to the anapole moment, and $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x})$ is the external current evaluated at the particle's location. Again, this vanishes if no other sources are around. Presumably, what this means is that in classical electromagnetism, you can show that all forces and torques cancel when you apply the source-free Maxwell equations, though I haven't worked this out personally.
The fact that an anapole can't be acted on by radiation, which is source-free, automatically tells us that it can't emit radiation either. The more general way to see this is to note that $L_{\mathrm{ana}}$ is a "contact term": it vanishes on the free equations of motion, which means that its coupling to the electromagnetic field can be removed entirely by a field redefinition. It really just represents a contact interaction between charged particles. And that's indeed how anapole moments are viewed in nuclear physics, where they're measured regularly. They have no direct electromagnetic effect, but they do affect scattering when particles get right on top of each other.
However, there are important differences between elementary moments, described in this answer, and the macroscopic moments one might make by winding coils of wire in the lab. For example, if we forget about anapole moments for a second, you could ask the much simpler question of whether a magnetic field can do work on a magnetic dipole moment. If it's an elementary dipole moment, corresponding to a term $i \bar{\Psi} [\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu] \Psi \, F_{\mu\mu}$, then the answer is yes. If it's a macroscopic one made from a loop of wire, then the answer is no, as follows immediately from the classical Lorentz force expression: any positive work done by pushing the whole thing is compensated by negative work done by slowing the charges inside. Accordingly, if you tried to make a macroscopic anapole moment using a toroidal solenoid, then it could well emit radiation or be acted on by radiation, depending on exactly how it's constructed. But in that case I suspect the description in terms of anapole and higher moments is not very useful and one should just solve Maxwell's equations directly.

Thanks, your answer means that the definition from the Wikipedia link in my question is blatantly wrong! There we read, on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_moment , that: a "polar (or magnetic) toroidal dipole (also called anapole) correspond to the field of a solenoid bent into a torus". If, OTOH, they are different things (one is a current distribution, the other just a contact term) then the somewhat paradoxical situation is resolved. But as "sources online seem to disagree", as you write, how can we find the authoritative definition of "anapole"?

@JosBergervoet To be honest, I'm not sure. I looked into this for a few hours a few years ago, but didn't totally resolve it. When the same kind of thing is important in several different fields of physics, it often gets several related but slightly different definitions, so that no one definition is "authoritative". It just depends on what you want to do. The definition I mentioned is more natural if you're considering scattering of particles, LPZ's is more natural if you're considering an actual toroidal solenoid. There might be yet more definitions used by others.

Is that just unfortunate? Or should it be intriguing?! In some way it seems that there might be new physics: if anapole means "no radiation" or "no field", what is the difference then with the long-known non-radiating currents? [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonradiation_condition ] Is there something missing perhaps, like the famous sporadic groups in The Classification? Will there be monsters?! More likely of course it's just a sloppy mix-up of names, or unclear explanation whether static or time-varying cases are meant, or a similar mundane explanation.
